# What's the difference between async and nonblocking in unix socket?

Tags: c, network-programming, nonblocking, asyncsocket

I'm seeing such code in nginx:

```
if(fcntl(ngx_processes[s].channel[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(s, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
...
if (ioctl(ngx_processes[s].channel[0], FIOASYNC, &on) == -1) {
...
```

Anyone can tell me what's the difference between `fcntl(s, F_SETFL, fcntl(s, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK)` and `ioctl(s, FIOASYNC, &on)` ,aren't `async` and `nonblocking` the same thing??

Comment: +1 your series of questions has taught me to steer clear of nginx. :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`FIOASYNC` toggles the `O_ASYNC` flag (which is usually set in `open(2)` or `fcntl(2)`) for a file descriptor, which will ask the kernel to send `SIGIO` or `SIGPOLL` to the process when the file descriptor is ready for IO.

`O_ASYNC` is not used often:

- it is extremely difficult to properly handle IO in signal handlers; they are best left as tiny as possible
- because signals interrupt the control flow of the program, they 'cost more' to run than standard system calls, such as `select(2)` or `poll(2)`
- signals provide less information than other calls: they only report one fd ready vs many fds that might be ready.

The `O_NONBLOCK` doesn't provide *any* notification to the user process that a fd is ready for `read(2)` or `write(2)` -- instead, it changes the behavior of `read(2)` and `write(2)` and similar calls to return immediately if the file descriptor isn't ready for reading or writing. `O_NONBLOCK` is typically used in conjunction with `select(2)` or `poll(2)` or [similar calls](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) to guarantee that the main loop of a client or server won't block on one specific peer, and thus starve all its peers.

Comment: @sarnold,so you mean both are the same thing?

Comment: Also `FIOASYNC` is a completely nonstandard/legacy way to do the equivalent of `O_ASYNC` with `open` or `fcntl`.

Comment: @cpuer: No, async and nonblocking are completely different concepts.

Comment: @cpuer: It may have a good reason to set the flag, but it should do so in the standards-sanctioned way, using `fcntl` with `O_ASYNC`, not some ancient 1980s-style `ioctl`.

Comment: @sarnold,I saw your change. When using `ASYNC` and notification callback is invoked,1.will the process stop its current routine ? 2. or both the current routine and the callback routine are running the same time?

Comment: @R..,can you describe the situation when `ASYNC` callbacks are invoked? Will it block the original process routine ?

Comment: It's not a callback but a signal. If a signal handler for the signal has been installed, it will asynchronously stop execution of the thread the signal was delivered to and execute the signal handler until it returns. After the signal handler returns, the interrupted thread will continue. Being asynchronous, signal handlers are rather dangerous, and there are mildly complex rules for what you can and cannot do from a signal handler. Breaking those rules results in undefined behavior and may *appear to work* but suddenly crash, deadlock, or corrupt memory in timing-specific ways.

Comment: @R: Can you cite the standard that specifies `fcntl` with `O_ASYNC` (or indeed mentions `O_ASYNC` at all)?